# Selecting element value from drop down list with selenium using POM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, page-objects

I'm trying to make a simple test to register in website - https://www.midomi.com/. I'm using c# and selenium but have stuck in selecting values from a dropdown list using Page object model. My project contains test class and page object folder with two classes inside her - home page and register page.

Register page: here I'm having problem to implement code to selecting values from the dropdown list

```
namespace MidomiRegisterPOM.PageObject
{
class RegisterPage
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    //type your email
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "email")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement Email { get; set; }

    //type your username
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "username")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement UserName { get; set; }

    //type your password
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "password")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

    //confirm your password
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "confirm_password")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    //here select from dropdown list your birth day, month and year       

    //mark privacy notice checkbox
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "tos_pp")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement PrivacyNotice { get; set; }

    //click Continue button
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "submitLink")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement ContinueButton { get; set; }

    public RegisterPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }
    public void RegisterToSite()
    {
        Email.SendKeys("testing@gmail.com");
        UserName.SendKeys("Tester");
        Password.SendKeys("testing");
        ConfirmPassword.SendKeys("testing");
        ContinueButton.Submit();
    }
```

I'm trying this but got an error:
[image]

Is there any way to select it with [FindsBy] like I'm selecting email, username and password field? Thanks

Here is my code without using POM:

```
    var birthMonth = driver.FindElement(By.Id("birth_month"));
    var selectMonth = new SelectElement(birthMonth);
    selectMonth.SelectByValue("5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included all the necessary libraries?

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

var birthMonth = driver.FindElement(By.Id("birth_month"));
var selectMonth = new SelectElement(birthMonth);
selectMonth.SelectByValue("5");
```

Or on one line:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("birth_month"))).SelectByValue("5);
```

Comment: This working only on project with one class. Here i've test class, page object folder with two classes inside - home page and register page

Comment: Can you paste more of your code? Would copying the current methodology not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that function to select a element from e drop down.The element parameter would be your POM property and the option parameter is your element with value that you want to be clicked.

```C#
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "birth_month")]
[CacheLookup]
public IWebElement BirthMonth{ get; set; }

public void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement element, string value)
{
    element.Click();

    var selecteElement = new SelectElement(element);

    selecteElement.SelectByValue(value);
}
```

Call it like this:

```C#
SelectElementFromDropDown(BirthMonth, 4);
```

Comment: In this code where to add Id("birth_month") and value "4"..

Comment: Thanks man. It's really works now. Because I have also BirthDay and BirthYear drop downs, I'm writing two more methods. It's not possible SelectElementFromDropDown method to takes 6 arguments. It's not cleanest code but good starting maybe

Answer (score -1):

How my final code looks. I wrote three methods for birth month, day and year. And called them by their names. I'm still trying to make method to takes 6 arguments if there's any way

```
namespace MidomiRegisterPOM.PageObject
{
class RegisterPage
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    //type your email
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "email")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement Email { get; set; }

    //type your username
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "username")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement UserName { get; set; }

    //type your password
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "password")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

    //confirm your password
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "confirm_password")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    // select from dropdown list your birth month
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "birth_month")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement BirthMonth { get; set; }

    // select from dropdown list your birth day
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "birth_day")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement BirthDay { get; set; }

    // select from dropdown list your birth year
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "birth_year")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement BirthYear { get; set; }

    //mark privacy notice checkbox
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "tos_pp")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement PrivacyNotice { get; set; }

    //click Continue button
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "submitLink")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement ContinueButton { get; set; }

    //method selecting birth month
    public void SelectMonth(IWebElement element, string option)
    {
        element.Click();

        var selecteElement = new SelectElement(element);

        selecteElement.SelectByText(option);

    }
    //method selecting birth day
    public void SelectDay(IWebElement element, string option)
    {
        element.Click();

        var selecteElement = new SelectElement(element);

        selecteElement.SelectByText(option);

    }
    //method selecting birth year
    public void SelectYear(IWebElement element, string option)
    {
        element.Click();

        var selecteElement = new SelectElement(element);

        selecteElement.SelectByText(option);

    }

    public RegisterPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }
    public void RegisterToSite()
    {
        Email.SendKeys("testing@gmail.com");
        UserName.SendKeys("Tester");
        Password.SendKeys("testing");
        ConfirmPassword.SendKeys("testing");
        SelectMonth(BirthMonth, "August");
        SelectDay(BirthDay, "15");
        SelectYear(BirthYear, "1999");
        PrivacyNotice.Click();
        ContinueButton.Click();
    }
}
}
```